# ARM assembly: how to swap array elements to implement sorting?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, swap

I am attempting to write a program to search for the median of an array after first sorting the array from smallest integer to largest integer. I am referencing a C program for finding the median of an array to translate it into the ARM assembly equivalent. I am having trouble figuring out how to swap a[j] with a[j+1] if a[j] > a[j+1].

Here is the C program:

```
 void swap(int *p,int *q) {
   int t;
   
   t=*p; 
   *p=*q; 
   *q=t;
}

void sort(int a[],int n) { 
   int i,j,temp;

   for(i = 0;i < n-1;i++) {
      for(j = 0;j < n-i-1;j++) {
         if(a[j] > a[j+1])
            swap(&a[j],&a[j+1]);
      }
   }
}

int main() {
   int a[] = {6,3,8,5,1};
   int n = 5;
   int sum,i;

   sort(a,n);
   
   n = (n+1) / 2 - 1;      // -1 as array indexing in C starts from 0
```

and here is the program I have written so far:

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m4
.fpu softvfp
.thumb

.section .data
.balign

array: .word 81,75,90,94,79,86,89,54,75,98, -1
size: .word 9

.section .text
.balign
.global main

Median:
        ldr r8, =array
        ldr r9, =size      //hard coded size of the array -1 is not meant to be included
        mov r1, #0     // i = 0
        mov r3, #0    // j = 0
        ldr r2, [r8, r1, lsl #2]  // getting a[j]
        ldr r4, [r8, r1, lsl #3]  //getting a[j+1]
        cmp r2, r4
        bgt swap

swap: // swap a[j] with a[j+1]
        str r2, [r4]
        




forever:
    b     forever
```

Comment: It might be easier if you don't worry about the existing `swap` function from the C Source code, and instead think about what it *does*. You have two values (stored in registers). One of these values should be stored in memory at `a[j]` and one at `a[j + 1]`. You have already loaded these values into their respective registers, now just store the values from the registers in their respective memory position, but switch which you store where. I.e. if you load `a[j]` into `r2` and `a[j + 1]` into `r4`, then store `r2` in `a[j + 1]` and `r4` in `a[j]`.

Comment: Also, branching to `swap` if greater doesn't make sense here, because that's the next instruction: if you don't take the branch, you'll go on to execute `swap` anyway.    Probably what you want to do instead is branch to the next iteration (which you haven't written yet) if *not* greater.

Comment: As an addendum to the comment by @NateEldredge, with assembler being what it is, keeping the `swap` label (or another suitable named label, together with some comments about what's happening) might still be a good idea.

Comment: A couple other bugs: `ldr r9, =size` loads the *address* of `size`.  `ldr r4, [r8, r1, lsl #3]` isn't `+1`, it's `array[i*2]` because you used an extra left shift, instead of a `+4` (bytes) as part of your addressing mode.  (ARM can only do reg+reg or reg+immediate;  You should use a pointer increment so you can do stuff like `ldr r2, [r1]` vs. `ldr r3, [r1, #4]`, and stores with the same addressing modes but opposite registers, like a compiler would when optimizing your C code.)